# Como usar posição fixed dentro de uma div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho uma div que tem seu `header` e seu conteúdo que tem um `height` fixo e esse tem *scroll*.
Como colocar `position: fixed` no `header` (onde é o titulo), sem que ele se mova quando o *scroll* for com a página?

Exemplo:

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div id="conversation">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>Título</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <ul>
                <li>Primeira conversa</li>
                <li>Segunda conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
                <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body, html{
    height: 150%
}    
#conversation{
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: 400px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
} 
.header{
    background: #4ECDC4;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 385px;
}
.content{
    margin-top:35px;
}    
ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFmMx/)

Comment: Não é a resposta pra sua pergunta, mas assim fica BEM mais simples: http://jsfiddle.net/7aQYh/1/

Comment: Não acredito que seja possível resolver esse problema mantendo a abordagem do `position: fixed`. Ao usar essa propriedade, você destaca o elemento da página, e ele passa a independer de qualquer hierarquia (ou seja, não dá para limitar em uma div). Assim sendo, acho que a solução do @Bacco é o caminho.

Comment: Jefferson, é isto que procura? http://jsfiddle.net/sF95J/

Comment: @Sergio, quase isso. O problema é que esse minha div não esta colada no topo. adicione por exemplo margin-top: 100px; e testa ai pra vc ver.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison, ok. Então é só juntar a posição do `.main`? Assim? http://jsfiddle.net/r95R8/

Comment: @JeffersonAlison você quer fazer janelas de chat no estilo do facebook?

Comment: @JeffersonAlison o mesmo que eu propus inicialmente, mas com margin-top: http://jsfiddle.net/7aQYh/3/ - aproveitei e tirei a margem do h3

Answer (score 6):

Quando dá `position: fixed` então o elemento passa a comportar-se como um elemento livre e independente da posição do seu parente. Se o que pretende é impedir esse comportamento "livre" com jQuery, pode fazê-lo mas devo referir que este código que deixo em baixo faz o mesmo que retirar o `position: fixed`, como o @Bacco sugeriu e é inferior em performance.

Mas vou assumir que você precisa mesmo de dar `position: fixed` e aí a minha sugestão é adicionar um "espião" de scroll para correr uma função que ajusta a posição do elemento tendo em conta a posição inicial e o scroll no momento.

```
var header = $('#conversation .header');
var mainPosition = $('.main').position();
$(document).on('scroll', function () {
    header.css('top', -$(document).scrollTop() + mainPosition.top + 'px');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/45B7H/

Comment: Só um detalhe aqui. Quando um elemento recebe `position:fixed`, ele fica livre/independente não somente do seu parente, mas do documento como um todo.

Answer (score 4):

Tente usar position absolute no header.
Por exemplo:

```
.header{
    background: #4ECDC4;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 385px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

O `position fixed` não se adequa muito bem à sua necessidade, o position que melhor se adequaria seria o `position:absolute`, mas eu preferi organizar melhor seu Css.
Para entender melhor como funcionam os *positions* você pode ler o artigo [**Propriedade position do css**](http://tableless.com.br/propriedade-position-do-css/).

> ### Position Fixed
>
> O position: fixed; irá fixar a posição do elemento na coordenada que você definir. A medida que a página é rolada, o elemento continua fixo na posição que você definiu e o conteúdo da página rola normalmente.
>
> Geralmente é usado para fixar elementos como cabeçalhos ou sidebars.

Ou seja o `position fixed` se mantém sempre fixo à janela e não ao elemento em q ele está inserido, por isso fiz modificações no seu `css` para que funcione exatamente como você precisa.

### Css

```
body, html{
    height: 150%
}

#conversation{
    width: 400px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
    background: #4ECDC4;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
}

.header h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.content{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    height: 400px;
}

ul{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Você pode observar o exemplo funcionando no

### [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/uFmMx/1/)