# Como fixar a posição de um elemento dentro de uma div com scroll( Com css )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

É possivel fixar um elemento( div, img, p ) em uma div com `scroll` e com `position:relative` e usando apenas css?

*Atualmente reposiciono a div usando a função `$('elemento').scroll()` e calculando o `scroolTop()` do elemento mas no IE( o pior browser do mundo ) existe meio que um delay e o elemento fica 'tremendo' por isso gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer isso só com CSS.

HTML:

```
<div class="divContainer">
    <div class="conteudoFixo">
        <h3>Objeto Fixo</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="conteudoNormal">
        <ul>
            <li>Primeira conversa</li>
            <li>Segunda conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>
            <li>Terceira conversa</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.divContainer {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
    position:left;
    overflow:auto;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    position: relative;
}

.conteudoFixo {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-color:#FF00FF;
    width:100%;
}
```

Link do exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/uQLzv/

Comment: Talvez [esta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16030/como-usar-posicao-fixed-dentro-de-uma-div) possa já ter respondido sua dúvida

Comment: Caputo obrigado pela resposta é que ja utilizava isso(javascript) para reposicionar minha div, mas no IE( maldito ) ocorre um atraso ai a div fica tremendo.
Mas enfim obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então amigo a solução é simples, não faz o mínimo sentido deixar a `.conteudoFixo` dentro de uma div com scroll que no caso do seu código é a div pai `.divContainer` ... o mais sensato seria deixar a div q vc quer fixa fora do scroll, fazendo com que apenas os itens de lista rolem junto com a div, dessa forma faça como eu fiz no seu código que editei.

http://jsfiddle.net/uQLzv/5/

Explicando a edição:

1- A div `.divContainer` deixa de ter a propriedade `height`, continua sendo relativa, e dentro dela seguem 2 divs, a `.conteudoFixo` e `.conteudoNormal` ... ambas possuem a propriedade `float:left` juntamente com `width:100%`, desta forma uma fica abaixo da outra na ordem da sua marcação HTML.

2- A div `.conteudoFixo` apenas possui uma estilização css pra dar beleza, estilize como preferir.

3- Já a div `.conteudoNormal`, preste atenção ... ESSA DIV QUE DEVE POSSUIR A PROPRIEDADE `overflow:auto` juntamente com `height: <Valor_que_vc_preferir>`, essa div vai conter os itens que vão rolar na caixa

Comment: Valew, eu 'manjo' AS3 e Javascript, começando Java precisando de algo estamos ai!

Answer (score 1):

Coloque isso em seu CSS:

```
.conteudoFixo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#FF00FF;
}
```

Comment: Desde ja obrigado pela ajuda. 

Então...é que quando eu uso o position:fixed a divFixa perde a referencia da divPai( fica por cima do scroll ) e não consigo controlar com o z-index;

Mas valew mesmo assim, vou continuar tentando agora tenho uma base.

Comment: qual realmente seu objetivo? podemos achar uma alternativa para o position:fixed e absolute.

Comment: Então é colocar a divFixo por cima de todo conteúdo sem contar espaça é tipo o fixed em relação a janela mas no meu caso seria em relação div( com scroll ).

Ahh, o meu objetivo é duplicar e fixar o header e colunas de uma tabela( posteriormente vou criar um plugin, os que encontrei não são tão flexiveis );

*Porfavor não relacione tabela a esta pergunta, Valew XD

Answer (score 1):

Eu alteraria o seu css, adicionando esse código a classe `conteudoNormal`.

```
.conteudoNormal{
    overflow:auto;
    height:200px;
}
```

E deixaria a classe `divContainer` assim:

```
.divContainer {
    width:300px;
    position:left;
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Então é que no meu caso a divFixa não pode 'empurrar' o conteudo normal e ficaria por cima mesmo, no meu caso seria o equivalente ao position fixed na janela( browser ) só que a divFixa teria como referencia a divContainer ao contrario da janela inteira. 
Valew desde já